# Written books - How do I make a hover event that displays a mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was using the book editor on minecraft.tools and saw there was a mouse over hover event that displays a mob. I added the information for it and created the book in game, but nothing appeared when I hovered over the text in the book. The segment for the hover and click event was:

```
{"text":"Spawn Test Mob","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/execute at shaeno run 
summon drowned ~ ~1 ~"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_entity","value":" 
{type:drowned,name:\\"johnny sins\\",id:\\"11cdf7cf-6dc0-4b6f-9e87-e06fd2377ce8\\"}"}}, 
{"text":"\\n"}
```

The hover event for displaying the items also didn't work and it just showed "Air" but I'll ask that as a separate question.

Pastebin of the entire command:
https://pastebin.com/bkBQqh51

Answer (score 1):

The `value` tag in hover events is deprecated. You should be using `contents` instead.

```
{
  "action":"show_entity",
  "contents": {
    "name": {"text":"johnny sins"},
    "type": "minecraft:drowned",
    "id": "11cdf7cf-6dc0-4b6f-9e87-e06fd2377ce8"
  }
}
```